# Is there any formulas or ways to convert .net Font.Size to html <font size?

Tags: html, .net, fonts, size, converters

The default font size in .net is 8.25 and it looks fine in programs, but if I set such size in html, the font becomes gigantic.
Is there any accurate formulas for conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font size in .NET is given in *point* (pt). You cannot do that with the [HTML `font` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2) (which is deprecated by the way). However, you can do so [in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props):

```
font-size: 8.25pt;
```

Exact rendering then could still vary, though. Your operating system has a dpi setting which controls how large a point is in pixels. Web browsers may or may not honor that and on top of that might even have their own zoom setting which further changes the font size. CSS however, [defines a pixel as ¾ of a point](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length), so `8.25pt` should be the same as `11px`.

Comment: This is good to know, but I also need some conversion to <font size

Comment: Did you read the linked pages? The actual font size specified by the `size` attribute of the `font` element in HTML is not specified at all. Every browser vendor is free to choose them. And they do. That element is deprecated for a reason, by the way. You should really use CSS for styling, *especially* if you need good, well-defined results.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. Might help you out

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwf9s90b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: this is cool info... but in there anythign related to HTML font?

Comment: What Joey said. HTML does not have one font size. It can use most from pt, em to px etc.

Comment: Gezzasa: HTML itself cannot use units for lengths. CSS can.

Comment: Lets not get too technical now...;). But I hear you. I'm self taught so my wording isn't always correct. What you said is what I meant.